# Laravel - pass ajax variables to model

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In my User Model i have this getter method:

```
public function getWorkedHoursInRangeAttribute($start, $end)
{
    $sum = [];
    foreach($this->workedTimes as $item) {

        if( ($item->start_time->gt($start)) && ($item->end_time->lt($end)) ){

            array_push($sum, ceil($item->end_time->diffInMinutes($item->start_time->addMinutes($item->break_time_min))/60 * 4) / 4 );

        }

    }

    return array_sum($sum);
}
```

And in my view i post this

```
function(start, end) {

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/users/workedhours',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
        data: {"start": start.format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"), "end": end.format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm")},
```

and i have this in my Controller

```
public function getWorkedHoursForRange(Request $request)
{

    $start = Carbon::parse($request->start);
    $end = Carbon::parse($request->end);


    return response()->json(['msg' => $start], 200);
}
```

and this route:

```
Route::post('users/workedhours', 'UsersController@getWorkedHoursForRange');
```

How can i take this start and end variables from ajax to my Model method and make calculation?

I will probably need to do something in my Controller...but what?

UPDATE:

in view i have this foreach loop for my table:

```
     <tbody>
     @foreach ($users as $user)
         <tr>
             <td><a href="{{ url('/user', $user->id)  }}">{{ $user->name }}</a></td>
             <td>{{ $user->total_time_current_year }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->total_time_last_year }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->total_time_current_month }}</td>
             <td>{{ $user->total_time_last_month }}</td>
             <td>here i need the calculation for date range</td>
         </tr>
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
```

Comment: You should convert make a new string called total and just get the time difference between start and end variables and that will be your difference and just return that in the response.

Comment: I do not know what authentication mechanism you have set up, but normally $user = Auth::user() will get you the current authenticated user and then you could call the getWorkedHoursInRangeAttribute() function on that user, passing in $start and $end. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two attributes in your model: start and end. That way you are able to access them in your accessor.

```
protected $start;
protected $end;

public function getWorkedHoursInRangeAttribute()
{
    $sum = [];
    foreach($this->workedTimes as $item) {

        if( ($item->start_time->gt($this->start)) && ($item->end_time->lt($this->end)) ){

            array_push($sum, ceil($item->end_time->diffInMinutes($item->start_time->addMinutes($item->break_time_min))/60 * 4) / 4 );

        }

    }

    return array_sum($sum);
}
```

You than make your AJAX call to the controller, loop through the users, set start and end vars to each user-model and return all users to the view. There you can access your accessor-attribute.

```
public function getWorkedHoursForRange(Request $request)
{

    $start = Carbon::parse($request->start);
    $end = Carbon::parse($request->end);

    $users = App\User::all();
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $user->start = $start;
        $user->end = $end;
    }


    return response()->json(['users' => $users], 200);
}
```

Comment: OK now i see that i have forgot to put my view and because of that you didn't get the whole picture....so i will update my question with view and you will understand it better. sorry guys :(

Comment: @lewis4u I think you need to specify what `workedTimes` is in your model. Is this set?

Comment: $calc = App\User::calculate($start, $end); its wrong used here. its not a static attr

Comment: did you see in my table....i have a foreach loop for all users and then i get the worked hours for all of them...and the table is sortable.....so now i need to have a dynamical last column for worked hours for specific range...i don't even know if that is possible

Comment: @sleepless yes...i already have a few get methods with worked times but this one should be dynamic

Comment: @sleepless if you have time for team viewer you can see it!?

Comment: @lewis4u how about the laravel-chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120609/laravel